# How can I proxy (or define a middleware) to block/allow some method calls in my React Component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, middleware

Let's say I have a React Component like the following :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class test extends Component {


    __method01() {
        //.... sime implentation
    }


    __method02(){
        //.... sime implentation
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default test;
```

What I want to achieve is to implement function that intercepts all or some methods call and avoid executing them under certain circumstances.

I was thinking about a Proxy pattern. But I'm not sure what could be the best (elegant) implementation for React.

Comment: We might need some more details. What requirements are causing you to reach for things like proxies? Can you not just add some code to the top of the methods? Like, start __method01 with `if (thisShouldntBeRunning()) return`?

Comment: Put another way, i think this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have problem X, you think Y might solve it, and so you're asking about Y. But instead you should be asking about X.

Comment: Yes about thisShouldntBeRunning... but I am looking for a more elegant implementation without the need to duplicate code around. it's not a XY problem IMHO. Since I'm straightforward asking how to implement w/ React a proxy or middleware here.

Comment: If i suggest a way to reduce code duplication that doesn't use proxies or middleware, would that be an answer to your question?